# An element $f$ that is integral over its affine coordinate ring: show there exists this open neighborhood

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

(Recall first the following definition: Let $R$ be an integral domain and $K$ its field of fractions. An element $a \in K$ is called an integral element over $R$ if there exists a polynomial $g = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 x + a_0 \in R[x]$ such that $g(a) = 0$. )

**Problem:** Consider an affine variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $R = \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n] / I$ be its affine coordinate ring, and let $K$ be its field of fractions. Prove that if $f \in K$ is an integral element over $R$, then for each point $x \in X$ there exists an open (in the usual Euclidean topology) neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a real constant $B > 0$ such that $|f(y)| < B$ for all $y \in U$ where $f$ is regular. Show that this claim is false in general if $U$ is required to be Zariski open.

**Attempt:** I'm given a hint that I should use the maximum principle for holomorphic functions. I don't really know how to find this open neighborhood $U$. First, I believe that $K \cong \mathbb{C}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)/I$ (can someone confirm this)?

So I assume $f \in K$ is integral over $R$. By definition there exists a polynomial $p(t) \in R[t]$ such that $p(f) = 0$. Can I assume that $f \in K$ is holomorphic?

Any help with this problem is appreciated!

Comment: With $I = (y^2-x^2(x+1))$ then $Frac(\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))) = \Bbb{C}(x)[y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1)))\cong \Bbb{C}(y/x)$ and a function is bounded on compact subsets of $\{ (x,y)\in \Bbb{C},y^2=x^2(x+1)\}$ iff it is in $\Bbb{C}[y/x]$

Comment: The maximum modulus works for curves, for higher dimensions too even if it is less obvious. Otherwise simply say that since $f$ is unbounded and the $a_m$ are bounded then $\sup_z\sum_{m\le n-1} a_m (z)f(z)^m  = o(\sup_z f(z)^n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the fact that $f$ is locally bounded in euclidean topology please take a look to [my answer of a duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481854/integral-rational-functions-are-locally-bounded/3482674#3482674). I was not aware of the fact that it is a duplicate (many thank to **reuns** for pointing it out and giving a link to this question).

Let me prove that there are such $f$ which are not locally bounded in Zariski topology.

**Fact** *Let $X$ be a smooth affine algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$. If $f$ is a bounded holomorphic function on $X$, then it is constant.*

**Proof.**
Every smooth affine alg. curve $X$ is an open Zariski dense subvariety of a smooth projective curve $\overline{X}$. If $f$ is bounded on $X$, then by Riemann removable singularity theorem we deduce that $f$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\overline{X}$. Now the only holomorphic functions on compact Riemann surfaces are constant and $\overline{X}$ (from the point of view of analytic geometry) is a compact Riemann surface. Thus $f$ is constant.

**Example 1.**
Pick a nonconstant regular function $f$ on smooth affine complex algebraic curve $X$. Then $f$ is unbounded on $X$ (by **Fact**) and hence it cannot be bounded on any nonempty Zariski open subsets of $X$. Indeed, any nonempty Zariski open subset of $X$ is cofinite and $f$ cannot be bounded on a cofinite subset of $X$ without being bounded on the whole $X$ ($f$ is continuous in euclidean topology). Clearly $f$ is integral over a coordinate ring of $X$ (it is an element of this ring, so this is obvious).

**Example 2.** You can also construct a more complicated counterexample. Pick $X$ an non-smooth (i.e. non-normal) affine complex algebraic curve $X$. Next fix a rational function $f \in \mathbb{C}(X)\setminus \mathbb{C}[X]$ which is integral over $\mathbb{C}[X]$. This is possible because $X$ is non-normal (by definition). Suppose now that $f$ is locally bounded in Zariski topology on its domain of definition. Then there exists an nonempty open Zariski subset $U$ of $X$ such that

1. $U\subseteq \mathrm{dom}(f)$
2. $U$ is contained in the smooth locus of $X$.

These follow because nonempty Zariski open subsets on $X$ are cofinite, smooth locus of $X$ and $\mathrm{Dom}(f)$ are nonempty Zariski open subsets of $X$. Now $f_{\mid U}$ is regular and bounded hence constant by **Fact** ($U$ is a smooth affine algebraic curve). Since $f$ is constant on a Zariski dense open subset $U$ of $X$, it is constant on $X$. This violates the assumption $f\not \in \mathbb{C}[X]$.

Comment: Do you have a reference to your 'fact'?

Comment: @Kamil Which part of the proof is not clear for you? Maybe I should add that $\overline{X}\setminus X$ is finite. Then the rest of the proof is an incarnation of Louville's theorem. I should also add that the fact does not hold for general Riemann surfaces. For non-compact Riemann surface like a unit disc $\mathbb{C}$ there are plenty bounded holomorphic functions (but note that the disc is not an affine algebraic curve).